# Kohler Shower Handle/Knob Removal (with no set screw)

Tags: shower, bathtub, valve

I'm having a very difficult time getting this shower/tub handle removed to change out the face plate and can't seem to find much information on it.  It's a Kohler brand, and I have an image attached for reference.  Reason for the change is aesthetics and the knob itself is wobbly/floppy (but still functional).

The handle is completely smooth and there are no set screws are to be found.  I've tried holding the circled area on the flat spots with a large wrench and hand turning the knob without luck (like those two pieces are threaded).  I've also tried turning the whole knob counter-clockwise with no luck.  Lastly I tried prying between the circled ring area and the knob (in the groove) but it seems like it's all one piece.  Does anyone have any tips or tricks?  I tried scouring Kohler's site for what model/part this is unsuccessfully.  I've poured some vinegar on the knob in the circled area as well to help dissolve some of the crusty water deposits.

I was able to free the grey plastic piece to locate the faceplate screws, but stuck with the knob.  Thanks in advance for any insights you may have!!

[image]

Comment: What about holding the handle and turning the ring with the wrench flats?

Comment: look further back

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  Still unsuccessful thus far. Since I don't plan to reuse these parts, I'm thinking of creating a hole in the front face of the knob help determine how this comes apart (screw or otherwise).

Comment: Is it like a door knob where there's a small opening where you poke in something long and skinny to release a latch?